# How to read values from a pressure controller using matlab

Tags: matlab

I am reading data from a pressure controller via RS232 as follows:

```
s=serial('COM1','BAU',9600,'parity','none','databits',8,'terminator','CR/LF');

fopen(s);
fprintf(s,'COM,2%r%n');
out=fscanf(s)
```

> out =
>
> 0, 7.6700E-05,5, 2.0000E-02

This how far I have gotten. Now I would like to get the data continuously and store it in text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May vary depending whether the command you send to the controller sends back one set of data or turns on continuous streaming but it might be as simple as:

```
fid = fopen('filetowriteto.txt'); % open a file

for n = 1:600 %e.g. to receive a set number of lines

    fprintf(s,'COM,2%r%n');
    out=fscanf(s);
    % you may want to check received data is valid
    fprintf(fid,out);

end

fclose(fid)
```

Or another example for continuous data coming from the controller:

```
fid = fopen('filetowriteto.txt');
lw = 0;
fprintf(s,'COM,2%r%n');

while lw < 600
out=fscanf(s);

    if ~isempty(out)
    fprintf(fid,out);
    lw = lw + 1;
    end

end

fclose(fid)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Is there any like if we want to run the loop infinty times.fid = fopen('filetowriteto.txt','w'); this worked for me..

Comment: If you just do `while true` it will go forever but remember to `fclose` after you break out of the infinite loop! Or you can have some check that breaks it out (e.g. upon receiving certain signal from controller).

Comment: Though i am able to read data continously but why is this warning...to stop the execution i am pressing ctrl+c Warning: Unsuccessful read: A timeout occurred before the Terminator was reached. 
Error using serial/fscanf (line 154)
Unsuccessful read: Error using serial/fscanf (line 154)
Unsuccessful read: Error using fprintf
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.